# OSGI bundle versions (Apache Felix)

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

Is it legal to use bundle versions like 1.01.0? Can't find any info on how this will work. I use Apache Felix implementation of OSGI.

Answer (score 0):

Felix is an OSGi framework implementation. It, therefore, must adhere to the [OSGi version syntax](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Version.html). This syntax makes `1.01.0` *identical* to `1.1.0`, which is identical to `000001.001`. That is, each of the *major*, *minor*, and *micro* part is an *integer*. It is parsed, where any leading zeroes are removed, and then used.

This *unlike* Maven. In Maven a version is an *opaque* string, leading zeroes are then not ignored and all these versions are different. This is a major issue when taking maven versions in the OSGi world because the version in Maven is so ill defined.